# Javascript file path not linking correctly

Tags: javascript, file, stylesheet

I'm trying to pull different stylesheets in my main.js folder depending on the time of day. However, I keep receiving a file not found error in the console.

When I open up inspect element. The day.css file appears in the DOM, but in the console I receive a file not found error and the file path is incorrect.

The browser shows the path as:
file:///Users/myname/Documents/directory/foodclock/day.css

but what it should be is:
file:///Users/myname/Documents/directory/foodclock/css/day.css

---This is my Javascript code----

```
function getStylesheet() {
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
if (0 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 5) {
document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='night.css' type='text/css'>");
}
if (5 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 11) {
document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='morning.css' type='text/css'>");
}
if (11 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 16) {
document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='day.css' type='text/css'>");
}
if (16 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 22) {
document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='evening.css' type='text/css'>");
}
if (22 <= currentTime&&currentTime <= 24) {
document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='night.css' type='text/css'>");
}
}

getStylesheet();
```

Any suggestions for troubleshooting this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add "css/" in every "href" element. Like this:

```
function getStylesheet() {
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
if (0 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 5) {
document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/night.css' type='text/css'>");
}
if (5 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 11) {
document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/morning.css' type='text/css'>");
}
if (11 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 16) {
document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/day.css' type='text/css'>");
}
if (16 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 22) {
document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/evening.css' type='text/css'>");
}
if (22 <= currentTime&&currentTime <= 24) {
document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/night.css' type='text/css'>");
}
}

getStylesheet();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify css/ in front of all href links because the css stylesheets are present in different directory `css`

```
function getStylesheet() {
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
if (0 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 5) {
document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/night.css' type='text/css'>");
}
if (5 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 11) {
document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/morning.css' type='text/css'>");
}
if (11 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 16) {
document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/day.css' type='text/css'>");
}
if (16 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 22) {
document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/evening.css' type='text/css'>");
}
if (22 <= currentTime&&currentTime <= 24) {
document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/night.css' type='text/css'>");
}
}

getStylesheet();
```