# Local Linked Javascript File Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, html, css, src

I'm having some trouble getting javascript to link into a HTML file. The external link works fine, but I need to make a few adjustments and link from a folder on my computer. I am completely stumped, I have no idea why I can link to an external js file and not one from my computer.

I have two identical Javascript files, but in different folders:

```
myWebsite/materialize.min.js
myWebsite/materialize/js/materialize.min.js
```

My file structure looks like this (I'm working on "materialui.html")

```
myWebsite/
    |
    |- materialui.html
    |- materialize.min.js
    |
    |- materialize/
            |- css/
            |- fonts/
            |- js/
                    |- materialize.min.js
                    |- materialize.js
```

I have tried linking to the local .js file using these methods:

```
//This one works:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script> 

//None of these work
<script src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="materialize.min.js" ></script>
<script src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="materialize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="materialize.min.js"></script>

//And I have also tried pasting the entire code into the script tag. No luck.
```

Here's the code for "materialui.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 

        <!-- This one works -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

        <!-- These do not -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize.min.js" ></script>

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

</head>

<body> 

<div class="container">
    <div id="t" class="chips chips-initial"></div>
    <div class="chips chips-placeholder"></div>

    <script>
    //$(document).ready(function(e) { ]);

        //$('.chips').material_chip();
        $('.chips-initial').material_chip({
            data: [{
                tag: 'Apple',
            }, {
                tag: 'Banana',
            }, {
                tag: 'Mango',
            }],
        });

        $('.chips-placeholder').material_chip({
            placeholder: 'Enter tag Name',
            secondaryPlaceholder: '+Tag',
        });

        $('.chips').on('chip.add', function(e, chip){
            var data= $('#t').material_chip('data');
            var l = data.length;
            var i;
            $(".chips-initial input").val('lll');
            for (i = 0; i < l; i++) { 
                //if (data[i].tag[0] = "#") {
                    //alert(data[i].innerHTML);
                    data[i].delete;
                //}
            }
        });


    </script>   

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have read these:

[Can't attach local Javascript file to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31767363/cant-attach-local-javascript-file-to-html)

[javascript not linking with html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946825/javascript-not-linking-with-html-file)

[Javascript file not linking to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175242/javascript-file-not-linking-to-html)

[Javascript file path not linking correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594863/javascript-file-path-not-linking-correctly)

[Javascript external file not linking correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979546/javascript-external-file-not-linking-correctly)

and ol' trusty

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp in case I just *missed* something

Comment: Try to add `./` before the path

Comment: Just tried
<script type="text/javascript" src="./materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
And it didn't work

Comment: This could be a wrong spelling of the names try copy/paste the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a 404 in the console? I would suggest editing your first js link to the following and removing the second one. Hopefully it works for you.

```
 <!-- These do not -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is it a 404 you're getting? Can you open up the html page locally and check that the file structure is as you think it is when it compiles? Hit F12 on Chrome and switch the tab to "Sources".

Comment: No 404, I'm getting what you get with no javascript in the head. The javascript below the body content works, I tested it using alert('hi');

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURED IT OUT
For some reason, I had to change the scripting at the bottom. I don't know why, but it works now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

</head>

<body> 

    <div class="container">
        <div class="chips chips-initial"></div>
    </div>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(e) { 

            $('.chips-initial').chips({
            data: [{
                    tag: 'Apple',
                }, {
                    tag: 'Microsoft',
                }, {
                    tag: 'Google',
                }],
            });

        });

    </script>   

    <script>
        M.AutoInit();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```